# How to tell if my system is "multiarch"?

Tags: kernel, dpkg, hardware-enablement-stack

Per the [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Desktop) wiki, "to install the newer HWE kernel derived from 15.10 (Wily)" there is a different set of packages to install depending on whether a system is multiarch or not.

How do I tell if my system is multiarch or not?

The wiki is "hinty", saying "you may find you need" to do this.

Comment: Usually means you run a 64bit OS, but also use packages that are 32bit. Run `uname -m` to check what kind of OS you have.  `x86_64` - 64bit, and `i686` - 32bit. Here's more info on multiarch https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec.

Comment: Thanks! I'm confident that I have 64 bit Trusty installed.  It's the part about using 32 bit packages that I need to check on, but don't know how to.

Comment: There will be nothing bad if you use the command for multiarch.

Comment: If you don't know whether or not you need 32bit packages, chances you great that you don't.

Comment: I'm not willing to break my system or install un-needed packages by taking these "chances", hence my question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`dpkg` supports installing packages for other non-native architectures using a system called multiarch. It was introduced in Ubuntu 11.04, so any later release should have it.

You can use `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` command to find the added foreign architectures on multiarch e.g.:

```
% dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

To find the native architecture, use `dpkg --print-architecture` e.g.:

```
% dpkg --print-architecture          
amd64
```

Alternately, you can also read the file `/var/lib/dpkg/arch` to get a list of added architectures (first one is native, although you can remove it):

```
% cat /var/lib/dpkg/arch             
amd64
i386
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed, and shows that I do need the "multiarch" packages.  Much appreciated.

Comment: the file /var/lib/dpkg/arch may only exist is at least one foreign architecture is installed