# 14.04 has not updated the kernel for the last, few upgrades I'm stuck on 3.13.0-93-generic

Tags: 14.04

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
Get:1 https://dl.winehq.org trusty InRelease
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg
Ign https://dl.winehq.org trusty InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages
Get:2 https://dl.winehq.org trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign https://dl.winehq.org trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign https://dl.winehq.org trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages
Hit https://dl.winehq.org trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit https://dl.winehq.org trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib Translation-en
Get:3 https://dl.winehq.org trusty/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en
Ign https://dl.winehq.org trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign https://dl.winehq.org trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 4,701 B in 7s (607 B/s)
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 818A435C5FCBF54A
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@CLM1001-Ubuntu:/home/stephen# apt-cache policy linux-generic
linux-generic:
  Installed: 3.13.0.139.148
  Candidate: 3.13.0.139.148
  Version table:
 *** 3.13.0.139.148 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.13.0.24.28 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzMVv.jpg
```

Comment: I had to trim my post to get within the 50000 size limit.  So I omitted results from the dpkg --list | grep linux-image command.

Comment: Did you do the hwe update back when it was suggested? I'm pretty sure you didn't, and at the time, it warned that you would stop getting updates if you didn't.

Comment: I most likely did not use "hwe" update (I don't remember seeing it) because I typically just click on the "install updates" button on the settings window.  Is there a safe way to go back and do that?

Comment: Yes, I will write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be an answer:  1) I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver into an empty partition on the same HDD where the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is installed.  2) Then I played around with GRUB2 and did grub-install to that hdd.  Then, when I rebooted, my Ubuntu 14.04 came up with kernel 4.4.0-109-generic.  Just in case it matters, I want to add that this system had two partitions with "/boot/grub" directories in them.  One of them was created a year or so ago, when I installed Debian 8.  So, now I have three OS's on the same disk, which is what I want, and Ubuntu 14.04 is my default.   One side-effect that I expected is that the video driver is blacking out my display periodically, which I also saw when I tried Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04.  I have the AMD RS880 [Radeon HD 4250] video card.  I will have to live with that unless I can find a way to get the a driver that works with this video card.  Thanks for all the help.  Askubuntu is a wonderful resource.  I have found almost all of my solutions through askubuntu.
I am going to mark this as answered if I can figure out how to do so.

Comment: I think the installation of Debian 8 may have messed up my grub settings.  When booting, it displayed the background image that was in the /boot/grub/ directory in the partition where Debian 8 is installed instead of the background image from the partition where Ubuntu 14 is installed.  So it was using those grub settings to boot instead of the ones from the /boot/grub/ directory in the partition from which Ubuntu 14.04 is booted.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your system has not been updated to the HWE stack. You can see from this graphic that 3.13 is the GA kernel, and in August 2016 users were advised to update to the HWE stack.

[image]

Here are the procedures for 14.04 from the official wiki [page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Trusty Tahr

The 14.04.2 and newer point releases will ship with an updated kernel and X stack by default. If you have installed with older media you can use the following to install the newer HWE kernel derived from 16.04 (Xenial):

Desktop

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
```

Multiarch Desktop

If you run a multiarch desktop (for example, i386 and amd64 on amd64, for gaming or Wine), you may find you need a slightly more involved command, like this:

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial:i386
```

Server

Install the HWE kernel derived from 16.04 (xenial):

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

When I did this, I had a question regarding the Multiarch Desktop part - how do I know if this applies to me?  Reference: [How to tell if my system is "multiarch"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736647/how-to-tell-if-my-system-is-multiarch/736651)

The answer is to use the command

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

and if you get an output, your system is multiarch.

Before attempting anything like this, I suggest you back up your system.

Comment: Thanks Organic Marble, I found that here [ https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack ] and was planning to try it when your response came up.  (Thanks for the quick response, by the way.)  I was wondering whether it is going to install drivers used by 16.04, but I will find out when I do this update.  root@CLM1001-Ubuntu:/home/stephen# lspci | grep Radeon
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 [Radeon HD 4250]
01:05.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4200 Series]

Comment: I ran the desktop "sudo apt-get install" command but, after reboot, still on  3.13.0-93-generic #140-...
So I ran the server version....  $ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial
[sudo] password for stephen: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-generic-lts-xenial is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Do I need to delete a bunch of stuff and then try the upgrade?  Maybe delete packages all the way back to 3.13.0.93-generic?

Comment: # sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-hwe-16.04
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-generic-hwe-16.04'
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04'

Comment: The one I have on my 14.04 machine is called `linux-generic-lts-xenial`. I guess those instructions may be out of date.  But you should be able to install the kernel package I just mentioned and get the 4.4.0-109-generic kernel.

Comment: I tried that with the same result.  Still stuck on 3.13.0-93.  Ended up having to restore the entire two terrabytes from Wednesday morning's backup.  Maybe I'll try installing 14.04 again from DVD to an empty partition, then upgrade that and see what it does.

Comment: I got the kernel updated by accident!  uname -a
Linux CLM1001-Ubuntu 4.4.0-109-generic #132~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 21:46:42 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@CLM1001-Ubuntu:/home/stephen#

Comment: Congrats! Good job.