# Is it worth restricting the apt sources file to use amd64 packages only in a server install?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, multiarch

I've read about Ubuntu using multiarch to supply i386 packages where required. On a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 Server 64bit there is not `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch` file.

This leads me to believe that multiarch support is not enabled by default. Is my assumption correct, and does the 64bit install use i386 packages and libraries?

Am I likely to run into issues if my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file lines all start with `deb [ arch=amd64 ] ...`, or is there any plausible benefit to doing so?

I'm asking as I maintain a private mirror and could save resources by only mirroring the amd64 architecture.

Comment: To find out if your system has multiple architectures enabled, run the following command: `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` I have multiple architectures enabled and I also have no file: `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch` https://askubuntu.com/questions/736647/how-to-tell-if-my-system-is-multiarch

Answer (score 0):

An `amd64` server installation does not have any `i386` package installed by default. After that, `i386` packages are installed if and only if the administrator installed them for some reason or other. Restricting your sources to `amd64` packages will cause problems if and only if you require `i386` packages; nobody can guess whether that is the case.